# Error in publishing a package from vendors in laravel 4 using config:publish command

Tags: git, laravel-4, package

I was trying to publish tecnick.com/tcpdf with this command

```
php artisan config:publish  tecnick.com/tcpdf
```

but it said Invalid argument exception configuration not found

and i did some research and come up with this command..

```
php artisan config:publish  tecnick.com/tcpdf --path="app/config/packages"
```

still error exception mkdir(): No such File or Directory

and tried this command also..

```
php artisan config:publish --path="app/config/packages"  tecnick.com/tcpdf
```

still error exception mkdir(): No such File or Directory

What do you Think Am I missing Here? Your help will be greatly appreciated..Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that tecnick.com/tcpdf doesn't have a Laravel-compatible config file to be published. Here's an alternative github.com/maxxscho/laravel-tcpdf